# Adding a ReplyTo within a function for Sendgrid

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sendgrid

I have a working function for using sendgrid web api. The function worked without any issue but now i would like to add in the ability to have a "ReplyTo" email address. The working code is as follows:

```
Private Function CreateMailMessage(ByVal fromAddr As String, fromName As String, ByVal toAddr As String, ByVal ccAddr As String, ByVal bccAddr As String, ByVal subject As String, ByVal contents As String) As SendGrid.IMail
    Dim returnVar As SendGrid.IMail = SendGrid.Mail.GetInstance
    returnVar.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(fromAddr, fromName)
    returnVar.Subject = subject

    If contents.Contains("<html") Then
        returnVar.Html = contents
    Else
        returnVar.Text = contents
    End If

    For Each aStr As String In toAddr.Split(CChar(";"))
        returnVar.AddTo(aStr)
    Next

    If Not (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ccAddr)) Then
        For Each aStr As String In ccAddr.Split(CChar(";"))
            'Sendgrid doesnt support CC via the webapi so we need to use Bcc
            returnVar.AddBcc(aStr)
        Next
    End If

    If Not (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bccAddr)) Then
        For Each aStr As String In bccAddr.Split(CChar(";"))
            returnVar.AddBcc(aStr)
        Next
    End If

    Return returnVar
End Function
```

and when adding the in the ReplyTo i tried the following:

```
Private Function CreateMailMessage(ByVal replytoAddr As String, ByVal fromAddr As String, fromName As String, ByVal toAddr As String, ByVal ccAddr As String, ByVal bccAddr As String, ByVal subject As String, ByVal contents As String) As SendGrid.IMail
    Dim returnVar As SendGrid.IMail = SendGrid.Mail.GetInstance

    If Not (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(replytoAddr)) Then
        returnVar.ReplyToList.Add(New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(replytoAddr))
    End If

    returnVar.From = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(fromAddr, fromName)
    returnVar.Subject = subject

    If contents.Contains("<html") Then
        returnVar.Html = contents
    Else
        returnVar.Text = contents
    End If

    For Each aStr As String In toAddr.Split(CChar(";"))
        returnVar.AddTo(aStr)
    Next

    If Not (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ccAddr)) Then
        For Each aStr As String In ccAddr.Split(CChar(";"))
            'Sendgrid doesnt support CC via the webapi so we need to use Bcc
            returnVar.AddBcc(aStr)
        Next
    End If

    If Not (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(bccAddr)) Then
        For Each aStr As String In bccAddr.Split(CChar(";"))
            returnVar.AddBcc(aStr)
        Next
    End If

    Return returnVar
End Function
```

it would seem Replytolist is not part of sendgrid? Anyone seen this?

Answer (score 1):

I maintain the SendGrid library. Sorry, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/58) that I haven't gotten around to fixing yet. In the meantime you can use the obsolete `ReplyTo`.

Comment: thanks for getting back to me! thought i was going crazy...if i use ReplyTo, i get... returnVar.ReplyTo = New System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(replytoAddr) i get an error about the 'System.Net.Mail.MailAddress' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of System.Net.Mail.MailAddress'